In the digraph, the shortest positive length closed walk through a vertex is a cycle through that vertex.
In spring18 mcs.pdf, it has Problem 10.4:

Problem 10.4. (a) Give an example of a digraph that has a closed walk including
two vertices but has no cycle including those vertices.
(b) Prove Lemma 10.2.6:
Lemma. The shortest positive length closed walk through a vertex is a cycle.


Lemma 10.2.6. The shortest positive length closed walk through a vertex is a cycle
through that vertex.
The proof of Lemma 10.2.6 is essentially the same as for Theorem 10.2.3; see
Problem 10.4.


Theorem 10.2.3. A shortest walk from one vertex to another is a path.
Proof. If there is a walk from vertex u to another vertex $v \neq u$, then by the Well
Ordering Principle, there must be a minimum length walk $\textbf{w}$ from u to v. We claim
$\textbf{w}$ is a path.
To prove the claim, suppose to the contrary that $\textbf{w}$ is not a path, meaning that
some vertex x occurs twice on this walk. That is,
$$
\textbf{w} = \textbf{e} \;\widehat{x} \;\textbf{f} \;\widehat{x}\; \textbf{g}
$$
for some walks e, f, g where the length of f is positive. But then “deleting” f yields
a strictly shorter walk
$$
\textbf{e} \;\widehat{x}\; \textbf{g}
$$
from u to v, contradicting the minimality of $\textbf{w}$. $\blacksquare$

$\widehat{x}$ definition:

In general, if a walk f ends with a vertex v and a walk r starts with
the same vertex v we’ll say that their merge $f\;\widehat{}\; r$ is the walk that starts with f and
continues with r. ... we’ll use the notation $f \;\widehat{v}\; r$ to describe the merge of
a walk f that ends at v with a walk r that begins at v.

Notice here we only considers digraphs since chapter 10 name is "Directed graphs & Partial Orders".
Also here we assume one not official definition of cycle which is not based on trail. This is different from wikipedia.

A closed walk is a walk that begins and ends at the same vertex. A cycle is a
positive length closed walk whose vertices are distinct except for the beginning and
end vertices.
Note that a single vertex counts as a length zero path that begins and ends at itself.
It also is a closed walk, but does not count as a cycle, since cycles by definition
must have positive length.

For (a), this QA answer for the same question seems to be wrong because it uses one different definition from the book. If using the book definition, $A\to D\to A$ is allowed and we can find the cycle $A\to D\to B\to A$ in the graph.
For (b), the counterexample in this answer doesn't work since the  backtracking edges is allowed in the digraph which won't be considered as duplicately visiting the same edge sequence. Its proof for (b) seems fine which is similar to the proof of Theorem 10.2.3. But IMHO if we solves with (a), then it seems to be one counterexample of (b).
Q:
Should I skip this problem since it is a bit weird? If it is not weird, then how to solve with it?

All the answers you linked to are about graphs, but your question is about directed graphs, so of course you're going to get confused looking at them! (There is also a reason why we allow $A \to D \to A$ for digraphs but not for graphs; in a digraph, this has two distinct edges. In fact, all directed cycles by this definition will, in fact, use distinct edges.)

@MishaLavrov Thanks for your notice. Could you give one example for (a) that may not influence the proof of (b) which is similar to the proof of the added Theorem 10.2.3 quote just now?

How can an example possibly influence the proof?? A proof is either correct or it isn't, independently of any examples. An example is either correct or it isn't. (If you think that you've found an example that shows that a proof is wrong, then either the proof is wrong, or else you're wrong about what the example shows; in both cases, it doesn't help to go look for a different example.)

@MishaLavrov Sorry. I said something incorrect. Could you give one example for (a)? And (a) may directly mean (b) is wrong as my post says, is it that case?

I can't see anything weird about the questions.
For the graph with set of vertice $\ V=\{1,2,3,4\}\ $ and set of edges $\ E=\{1\rightarrow2,2\rightarrow1,2\rightarrow3,3\rightarrow2,3\rightarrow4,$$\,4\rightarrow3\}\ $ the sequence
$$
1,1\rightarrow2,2,2\rightarrow3,3,3\rightarrow4,4,4\rightarrow3,3,3\rightarrow2,2,2\rightarrow1,1
$$
is a closed walk including the two vertices $1$ and $4$, but there's no cycle including those vertices, because any closed walk that includes them must pass through vertices $2$ and $3$ at least twice.
As a hint for answering part (b), consider the question of whether a closed walk in which any non-terminal vertex appears more than once can ever be the shortest closed walk starting and ending at its terminal vertex.  Can you see why the answer must be "no"?
Addendum
Your cited text's definition of cycle seems to me to be ambiguous, and open to being interpreted as not precluding its terminal vertex from appearing more than twice.  The authors probably didn't intend it to be interpreted in that way, but if they did, then my original example for answering (a) doesn't work, because
$$
3,3\rightarrow4,4,4\rightarrow3,3,3\rightarrow2,2,2\rightarrow3,3
$$
would then be a "cycle" including both vertices $2$ and $4$ according to the above (probably mistaken) interpretation.  I have now modified the example so that it works, even using that interpretation. Any closed walk in the above-defined graph that contains vertices $1$ and $4$ must include both vertices $2$ and $3$ at least twice.  Since at least one of these must be a non-terminal vertex of the walk, it can't be a cycle even under this broader interpretation.

Thanks. 1. The key part of (a) is those vertices while (b) says "a vertex" based on "shortest". So their constraints aren't same. I misunderstood the problem originally. 2. Following your hint, that will lead to the contradiction with the "shortest" assumption. This is same as the reference answer for (b) in the question post. 3. Small typo in your answer: $2\to 1,1$.

Thanks for picking up the typo, now fixed.

IMHO the problem said in "Addendum" is precluded by the text. "whose vertices are distinct except for the beginning and end vertices." may mean only "the beginning and end vertices" can be same which preclude the duplicity of terminal vertex inside the walk. This exception may be only to ensure "closed". This depends on how we understand that sentence.

Yes, on re-reading the sentence, I now believe that's the way it was intended to be read.  Nevertheless, I still think it's ambiguous, and open to be read in the way I (mis)interpreted it.  I'll update my answer in the light of this realisation.
